# When passing a struct by reference (as an UnsafeRawPointer) why must it be from a `var`?

Tags: swift, memory

Why does &copy in the below code need to be based on a `var`, why can't it be a `let`?

```
var mutableCopy = instanceOfA 
let data = Data(bytes: &mutableCopy, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: instanceOfA))

let immutableCopy = instanceOfA 
// Cannot pass immutable value as inout
let data = Data(bytes: &immutableCopy, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: instanceOfA))
```

Edit: To avoid confusion: I'm totally aware of how `inout` works. My problem is that the Data.init(bytes:,count:) doesn't take an `inout` but just a plain `UnsafeRawPointer` and since it's not mutable, why does it require a `var` rather than a `let`?

Comment: The `&` prefix denotes an `inout` property and an inout property is one that can be mutated by the function it is passed to. The title of your question is not asking the right question. The problem is not about an object being passed by reference but rather an object being passed into a function as an `inout` property.

Comment: @fakegirlfriends I may be wrong but have a look at the initialiser: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1780158-init. It doesn't specify it as `inout`. So there seems to be some kind of shorthand for turning a reference to an address (&) into a UnsafeRawPointer, and I'm unsure how that works, and why it only works with a var and not a let (I'm sure it's something about let's not having an address or something).

Comment: That is because in Swift, when you deal with `UnsafeRawPointer`, you can take advantage of *implicit bridging* which the Swift language provides you. So instead of passing a pointer directly, you can pass it an `inout` property that implicitly creates the pointer for you. Swift wants to be a higher-level language than C, and it is, but because Swift is still a relatively new language, there is still a lot of interoperation between Swift and C and thus bridging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From the Apple document of [`UnsafeRawPointer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsaferawpointer):-**

`Implicit Casting and Bridging`:-

> When calling a function or method with an `UnsafeRawPointer` parameter, you can pass an instance of that specific pointer type, pass an instance of a compatible pointer type, or use Swift’s implicit bridging to pass a compatible pointer.

Now what you have used is *implicit bridging*. You can use Swift’s *implicit bridging* to pass a `pointer to an instance` or to the `elements of an array`. Now `inout` is used to implicitly create a pointer to an instance of any type and `inout` cannot be constant so you need to declare your instance as `var`.

Comment: Except that https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1780158-init doesn't take an `inout` argument, it just takes an `UnsafeRawPointer`. "&" is a way to pass an address reference, that's why we use it when passing into an `inout`. But here it needs an address reference, and I'm unsure why it needs to be mutable, since it's not a `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`.

Comment: @TheisEgeberg Please check updated answer with more details.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up for me!